# How to solve the equation in terms of $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

How to solve following equation in terms of $x$:
 $$\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) + \frac{1}{2}\ln\left|1+\frac{y^2}{x^2}\right|=\ln\left|\frac{y}{x}\right|+c_1.$$
I am thinking of taking $e$ on all the terms. Please someone help me solve this. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that such a solution exists in an explicit form?

Comment: Simplify with $y=x\tan u$ and $c_1=\ln C$ then you have $C\sin u=e^u$ or $C\sin\dfrac{y}{x}=e^\frac{y}{x}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can find you an explicit form solution with some restrictions to $x$ and $y$; namely, if we require that $x^2+y^2=1$ and that $-1\le x\le 1$ and $-1\le y\le 1$, we get $x$ and $y$ as components on a unit circle and can set $x=\cos\theta$, $y=\sin\theta$. Then:
$$\begin{align*}
\theta+\frac{1}{2}\ln\left|1+\tan^2\theta\right|&=\ln\left|\tan\theta\right|+c_1\\
e^\theta \sqrt{1+tan^2 \theta}&=e^{c_1}\tan\theta\\
e^{\theta-c_1}&=\frac{\tan\theta}{\sec\theta}\\
e^{\theta-c_1}&=\sin\theta\\
e^{\theta-c_1}&=\sqrt{1-\cos^2\theta}\\
e^{\cos^{-1}x-c_1}&=\sqrt{1-x^2}\\
\cos^{-1}x&=c_1+\ln\left|y\right|\\
x&=\cos(c_1+\ln\left|y\right|)
\end{align*}$$

Keep in mind however that these are some pretty tight restrictions, but I'm sure there's probably a way to circumvent some of them. I don't think (although don't quote me here) that one could solve for $x$ explicitly without some kind of restriction to simplify things, as you'll have something along the lines of $f(x,y)=e^{g(x,y)}$ which I think is usually not expressible easily.

Comment: I need to solve for y, not x.

Comment: Then your answer would be $sin(c_1+\ln(y))$ by the same reasoning.